# adding letters and character in a column using awk or sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file which look like this:

```
A3 124.406526 8.281803
A3' 125.000684 8.389677
K4 123.072842 8.166373
K4' 120.092553 8.269080
```

I want to add characters in the 1st column, and the file will should be like:

```
A3N-H 124.406526 8.281803
A3'N-H 125.000684 8.389677
K4N-H 123.072842 8.166373
K4'N-H 120.092553 8.269080
```

How can I do this in a easy way by awk or sed?

Comment: This is almost unreadable, please reformat your question with `code tags`.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)/\1N-H/' file.txt
```

- `([^[:blank:]]+)` matches the first field (`^`), and put in only captured group
- In the replacement, `N-H` is appended to the first field, `\1N-H`

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub("$", "N-H", $1)}; 1' file.txt
```

- `sub("$", "N-H", $1)` substitute the end of first field (`$`) with `N-H`, this necessarily means an append operation, in place
- `1` is just a placeholder for `true` so that the (modified) record is printed

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                               
A3 124.406526 8.281803
A3' 125.000684 8.389677
K4 123.072842 8.166373
K4' 120.092553 8.269080

% sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)/\1N-H/' file.txt
A3N-H 124.406526 8.281803
A3'N-H 125.000684 8.389677
K4N-H 123.072842 8.166373
K4'N-H 120.092553 8.269080

% awk '{sub("$", "N-H", $1)}; 1' file.txt    
A3N-H 124.406526 8.281803
A3'N-H 125.000684 8.389677
K4N-H 123.072842 8.166373
K4'N-H 120.092553 8.269080
```

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, the one-liner:

```
awk '$1=$1"N-H"'
```

Comment: This will rebuild the whole record with space as new FS.

Comment: @heemayl I don't see any other field separation in the sample data.